# How to make methods referred through wsdl deprecated/Obsolete in c#?

Tags: c#, wcf

method1 is present in service s1,
now method1 is moved to service s2.

How to make a notification to the client method1 should be used from s2 
and also throw an error if client uses method1 from service s1 ?

Comment: If you want to be RESTful, return `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` as your response with `Location: ` set to the new address.

Comment: Thanks Dai, but I am using WCF service

Answer (score 0):

```
[Obsolete("Method1 is deprecated, please use Method2 instead.", true)]
```

use above code above the definition of obsolete method.

Comment: Hi Akshey, As per this link,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404863/mark-deprecated-fields-in-wcf-contract      it says [Obsolete] property wont work for wsdl references

Comment: I guess then you need to add comment  to mention to the client that method is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to remove operations from the service contract in general as it introduces breaking change and as such should be avoided in single version of API. It would be better to only inform a client/consumer about the change in version X of API and do the breaking change in version X+1 of your API.

However, if you want to inform client/consumer about some planned changes or have any other need to add certain "extra" information to the operation contract, you might take a look at [IWsdlExportExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlexportextension.aspx) interface, create a custom attribute that implements it and annotate particular operations.

You may take a look at [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/10/05/wcf-extensibility-wsdl-export-extension/) for detailed reference.